# What is the female matching connector to this male circular connector?

Tags: identification, connector, power-connector, circular

I was wondering if anybody knows a part number for the 6-pin female matching connector to the 6-pin male circular connector shown below ?

[image: It is from a Weller soldering iron...]

Comment: Couldn't give you a part number, but that looks familiar... Is that from a Weller soldering iron?

Comment: Yes its from a Weller ;-)

Comment: There may be a number of options, for example panel mounted or in-line.

Comment: probably a panel mount ...

Comment: Is this the same connector -https://www.eevblog.com/forum/repair/anyone-know-this-type-of-connector/  if so, it may be a custom part.

Comment: Unfortunately no it isn't, but it is some type of DIN type with a more symmetrical pin arrangement.

Comment: hmmm ... looks like I may have found it on Farnell ... it's an Amphenol part perhaps with a custom key ...

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with another Weller project and my conclusion was that the amphenol sine connectors could be made to work and I found nothing better/closer but as they say, likely a custom part.

Answer (score 0):

Connectors are a kind of a rabbit hole! There are soooo many connectors out there! Your best bet would probably be to contact an electrical parts distributor, and talk to a representative (Mouser, Arrow, etc) If that doesn't work, get your hands on a scrapped-out Weller, and extract the left-over connector. Sometimes people sell broken things real cheap on e-bay.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I used my [Connector Identification Utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=round_conn&u=circular_conn&fl=000000030000200000002013000-15c-%7C6%7C1%7C%7C%7C%7C) and it listed 4 possibilities, of which the Hirose RP6 was the closest.

If that is not it, please give additional details: inner diameter of the locking ring, shell material (plastic? metal?), fastening method.